# Out of memory error only four images i m taking whether its camera or from gallery and sending to the other activity

Tags: android, image, bitmap, uri, sharedpreferences

Out of memory error only four images i m taking whether its camera or from gallery and sending to the other activity
any body is there to help me in and getting me out this error 
thanks
here is my code for the first activity this working but when images comes to other activity its show out of memory error

```
     viewImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
     viewImage1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);

     viewImage2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);

     viewImage3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4);

    //send to data other Activity
     Button send= (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);   
     send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
     {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             Intent in=new Intent(AttachImageActivity.this, PostAddActivity.class);

                startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    //Add images to the imageview 
    addImage=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
                    if(i==4)
                    {
                        i=0;
                    }

            selectImage();

                            }
                     }
                            );
```

}

```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
   {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
            if (requestCode == 1) 
         {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();




              Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
               int size = 50;

             Bitmap bitmapsimplesize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail ,thumbnail.getWidth() / size, thumbnail.getHeight() / size, true);

        if(i==1)
        {
            SharedPreferences imagepath1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = imagepath1.edit();
            editor.putString("picturePath1",picturePath);
            editor.commit();

            viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        }
        else if(i==2) 
        {
            SharedPreferences imagepath2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = imagepath2.edit();
            editor.putString("picturePath2",picturePath);
            editor.commit();

            viewImage1.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);


        }
        else if(i==3) 
        {
            SharedPreferences imagepath3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = imagepath3.edit();
            editor.putString("picturePath3",picturePath);
            editor.commit();

            viewImage2.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        }
        else if(i==4) 
        {
            SharedPreferences imagepath4 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = imagepath4.edit();
            editor.putString("picturePath4",picturePath);
            editor.commit();

            viewImage3.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        }


    }

    else if (requestCode == 2) 
    {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
        String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
        c.close();

      //  myList.add(picturePath);
        /*       File f = new File(picturePath);
        String filename = f.getName();


        //Log.i("image path", imagepath);
        Bitmap imageData = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        // Bitmap imageData = null;
         imageData = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
         */

        Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        int size = 10;
        Bitmap bitmapsimplesize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail ,thumbnail.getWidth() / size, thumbnail.getHeight() / size, true);
        thumbnail.recycle();
        Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
        if(i==1)
        {
            SharedPreferences imagepath = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = imagepath.edit();
            editor.putString("picturePath1",picturePath);
            editor.commit();

            viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapsimplesize);
        }
        else if(i==2) 
        {
            SharedPreferences imagepath2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = imagepath2.edit();
            editor.putString("picturePath2",picturePath);
            editor.commit();

            viewImage1.setImageBitmap(bitmapsimplesize);


        }
        else if(i==3) 
        {
            SharedPreferences imagepath3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = imagepath3.edit();
            editor.putString("picturePath3",picturePath);
            editor.commit();

            viewImage2.setImageBitmap(bitmapsimplesize);

        }
        else if(i==4) 
        {
            SharedPreferences imagepath4 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = imagepath4.edit();
            editor.putString("picturePath4",picturePath);
            editor.commit();



            viewImage3.setImageBitmap(bitmapsimplesize);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before display bitmap put it in try catch block for out of memory exception.

Please go through this tutorial.

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

I hope this may help.Thanks!